# How to split/share teleportation portal scroll in DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2

I've been playing DotA for years now but recently I got in an interesting situation and figured out that I don't know how to share TP scrolls.

You can of course buy in stash and drop from there, buy in stash and use courier to deliver to ally, but not proper "sharing".

So... is there any way if you have 2 scrolls (stacked, in inventory), to give one (not both) to an ally? (like you share tangos or wards with Ctrl + left-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Town Portal Scrolls are among the strongest items in the game, and being caught without one in a situation where you desperately need it is meant to be punished.